# React.js - TypeScript doesn't alert a wrong prop value when I use destructuring

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I'm pretty new to using TypeScript but so far loving it. But today I've encountered an issue that I could not figure out.

Let's say a parent component A delivers a function that accepts a numeric value to the child component B. Why there is no validation for the type of argument that is expected?

**A.tsx**

```
export const A = (): ReactElement => {
  const x = (n: number = 0): void => {
    alert(n);
  };
  return (
    <B x={x} />
  );
};
```

**B.tsx**

```
export const B = ({ x }) : ReactElement => {
  return (
    <button type='button' onClick={() => x(`string`)  /* <--- Should only accept a number */ }> 
      alert a number
    </button>
  );
};
```

Should I add the typing to the destructive props? And/or how?

Answer (score 2):

You did not give any props types for function x.

Hence typescript doesn't whether x function only accept number.

Try this.

```
interface Props {
  x: (n: number) => void;
}

export const B = ({ x }: Props) => {
  return (
    <button type='button' onClick={() => x(`string`)  /* <--- Should only accept a number */ }> 
      alert a number
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is there an inline way to do so without the interface?

Comment: @Acri yes, you can, just.. paste the type in place of `Props`

Comment: If you don't want to use interface then u can do like this.

({ x }: { x: (n: number) => void})